# Is there a downside to calling new Date() multiple times

Tags: javascript, date, factory

I have a factory that creates a new entity and it calls new Date() multiple times to fill multiple fields like shown below:

```
  dateJoined: format('yyyy-MM-dd')(new Date()),
  createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
  updatedAt: new Date().toISOString()
```

one of my senior engineers suggested saving new Date() in a const and using it instead of calling new Date() multiple times, so the above code would change to be like this:

```
  const date = new Date();
  dateJoined: format('yyyy-MM-dd')(date),
  createdAt: date.toISOString(),
  updatedAt: date.toISOString()
```

He mentioned that one of the reasons for calling new Date() one time only is that there might be a millisecond difference between dates if we call it multiple times.

I am curious how likely is that to happen? and are there other benefits to calling new Date() one time only?

Comment: Probably it depends on the system. I would expect that on slow devices it can definitely happen. After playing around a bit in the console, on my system I got a different date after creating 10 individual dates. Another benefit of working with only one date object is that it's faster.

Comment: Does it really matter how likely that is? The code is definitely faster, cleaner and works as expected, unlike the code that calls `new Date` multiple times at different times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried it in my browser using this script:

```js
var diff=0;
for (var i=0; i<10000; i++) {
    var d1=new Date();
    var d2=new Date();
    var d3=new Date();
    if (d1.getTime()!=d2.getTime() || d1.getTime()!=d3.getTime()) { 
        diff++;
    }
}
console.log(diff);
```

and there are some iterations where the three dates are not equal. Typically, around 8 per 10000.

This is exactly the kind of inconsistency that passes many test runs but almost inevitably will bite you in production. Avoid it and follow your senior's advice.

Comment: Good answer, I made an executable snippet out of it. One more notable thing to mention, it probably depends on the system how many inconsistent results are returned (browser, processor, OS, ...). Generally I would expect higher numbers on slower systems.

Answer (score 2):

Using a single new Date() instance stored in a constant is generally a good practice.

- First, it ensures **consistency** across your dateJoined, createdAt, and updatedAt fields, as there can be millisecond differences between consecutive new Date() calls, as you said.
- Second, it slightly improves performance by reducing the load associated with creating multiple Date objects (few milliseconds, not that much but depends on your project and how many times you call it)
- Lastly, this approach enhances code readability and maintainability: centralizing one and only one date.

Answer (score 1):

In your example you store formatted string in your object properties.
So it's totally OK to use the same date like your senior dev suggested.

But in general the most important is mutability. The problem is `Date` isn't a primitive and is mutable.
So if in your example the dates would be stored as dates it is quite risky suggesting to use the same `Date` for different semantic values.

If you mutate some date for example `obj.createdAt.setMinutes(0, 0, 0)` you essentially change `updatedAt`.
So the thumb of rule is to have `Date` immutable.

You can use any date library that operates on dates in immutable way.
Creating new `Date` is quite fast process and it isn't worth to have duplicated dates to have some speed optimizations in expense of risks of having dangerous side effects because of mutability.

If you want to use a `Date` in another variable just clone it `new Date(dt)`. Never have copies of dates and treat them as immutable primitives.

Regarding your example you can even optimize it further:

```js
const date = new Date().toISOString();

const obj = {
  dateJoined: date.slice(0, 10),
  createdAt: date,
  updatedAt: date
};

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that my entity's fields are readonly, so I cannot directly modify createdAt or updatedAt in the way that you mentioned. Does this solve the immutability concern that you had?

Answer (score 0):

Your senior engineer is right actually, It's best practice to create a single Date object and use it again for the following reasons and many more:

**Performance**: By not instantiating new objects frequently, you avoid the unnecessary overhead of repeatedly instantiating new objects.

**Maintainability**: if you ever need to adjust the format of the dates or take care of any date manipulation-related changes, you just need to do it once.

**Preventing Bugs**: Mistakes will need to be fixed each time it happens. It is less likely to introduce problems and easier to manage and update the code when there is only one constant.